# How to ensure the order of user callback function in OpenCL?

Tags: callback, opencl, nvidia

I am working on OpenCL implementation wherein the host side particular function has to call every time the clEnqueueReadBuffer is done executing.

I am calling the kernels in a loop. It will look like below in an ordered queue.
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() -> clEnqueueReadBuffer(&Event) ->
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() -> clEnqueueReadBuffer(&Event) .......

I have used clSetEventCall() to register Events in each read command to execute a callback function. I have observed that, though the command queue is an in-order queue, the order of the callback function does not execute in-order.

Also, in OpenCL 1.2, it has a mention as below.

> The order in which the registered user callback functions are called
> is undefined. There is no guarantee that the callback functions
> registered for various execution status values for an event will be
> called in the exact order that the execution status of a command
> changes.

Can anyone give me a solution? I want to execute the callback function in order.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to subscribe the same callback function to both events. In the callback code, you can check the status of each relevant event and perform the operation you want accordingly.

Note that on some implementations, the driver will batch multiple commands for execution.
The immediate effect is that that multiple events will be signaled "at once" even though the associated commands complete at a different time.

```
// event1 & event2 are likely to be signaled at once:
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel();
clEnqueueReadBuffer(&event1);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel();
clEnqueueReadBuffer(&event2);
```

Wheres:

```
// event1 is likely to be signaled before event2:
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel();
clEnqueueReadBuffer(&event1);
clflush(queue);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel();
clEnqueueReadBuffer(&event2); 
clflush(queue);
```

I would also check on which exact thread the callbacks are invoked.
Is it the same thread each time? or a different one? If the implementation opens a new thread for this task, it might be wiser to open a single thread yourself and wait for events in the order that you wish.